# In *Wizard's First Rule*, why can't the court artist James target Kahlan?

Tags: magic, magical-theory, the-sword-of-truth

I was listening to the *Wizard's First Rule* on audiobook the other day, and it got to the part where they were dealing with Queen Milena.  Zedd said (paraphrasing, referring to James, the court artist) "His magic can't target me or Kahlan, but it can target you, so be careful."
They do not go into why it is that James' spells cannot target Kahlan.  I'm assuming that they can't target Zedd because

> he is the First Wizard

but why wouldn't he be able to target Kahlan?

Comment: Presumably, because she is First Confessor, or a Confessor in general, and that makes her immune. AFAIK, it's never explained beyond this, but much of the series talks about how Confessors have unique magic.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that; just didn't know if I missed something while I was reading (sometimes I skim excessively) Listening it brought it to mind, and I thought this would be a good place to ask. Thanks!

Comment: It *is* a good place to ask. I just can't compose a good answer right now, although I have all the eBooks (and physical books). If someone else doesn't get to it, I'll try for a more detailed answer for you sometime later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is not definitively known

You didn't miss anything in *Wizard's First Rule*; Zedd states that Kahlan and Richard can't be spelled by the court artist's drawings, and Richard later repeats that. However, it is not elaborated in either case as to why that is.

It's not due to the presence of magic. Zedd tells Richard that he could train him to be a wizard, and it's no surprise that this potential is explored in later books. So all three have the potential for magic, but only Richard is vulnerable.

### Perhaps there is some sort of protection that a wizard can cast?

Not sure if you have finished the book, but we see that Darken Rahl is able to make himself immune to certain magic. Because such immunities exist, it would stand to reason that Zedd could have cast a protection against this sort of magic on himself if he could. Given the close relationship between the confessors and the Wizards, perhaps Kahlan had such a protection cast on her when she was younger.

### Perhaps Zedd is immune because his wizard's web means he can't be identified?

When Richard discovers the drawing that James made, he tries to erase the Sword of Truth from it:

> Then [Richard] saw it. The man in the drawing was as tall as he, but the rest of the drawing was larger still. It was crude, but he knew it was him. The sword held in the right hand had the word *Truth* written on it. […]
>
> He pulled the stone out and immediately started erasing the sword, hoping that would take away his identity, take the spell off him. The lines erased only with great difficulty.

Let's assume that Richard is on to something here; the drawing worked because it identified him. Zedd's wizard's web prevented people from remembering who he was. While it seems people could still remember him after he cast the web, perhaps it was harder for people to remember who he was due to the web. Without a way to identify him, Zedd could not be targeted and was effectively immune.

### Perhaps Kahlan's unique Confessor power made her immune?

Kahlan can certainly be identified (by her long hair and dress, if nothing else), so the only possible explanation aside from some sort of protection cast on her is that her Confessor magic somehow makes her immune. To my knowledge, there aren't any other powers that she is immune to, so this would be an unusual case if she was immune to it.

### Later books don't provide any clues

The next time we see this sort of magic appear is nine books later in *Phantom*. By that point, Richard's magic potential has grown, yet he doesn't seem to have any sort of defense against this magic. Unfortunately, the individual casting the spell is only interested in spelling Richard and not Kahlan or Zedd, so it doesn't indicate why they are immune.